# Load data from multiple data files into multiple tables using single control file

Tags: sql-loader

I have 3 data files and 3  tables. Is there any way to enter the data from the data files to their respective tables using only a single control file using parameters.

I know that we can use multiple datafiles to insert data into single table but i want multiple datafiles to insert data into multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done it, but you can specify multiple files as long as they are the same layout by using multiple INFILE clauses.  Then as long as there is some identifier in the record, you can use multiple INTO TABLE clauses, each with its own WITH clause.  See the [control file reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1006645) for more info.  Please let us know how it works out.